# Permissions import from Active Directory

Tags: python, active-directory, pyqt4, user-permissions, user-data

I am writing a program to import and export users information. Basically A User Data System. 
 My Client ask me as well to implement a function for importing users with such and such permissions and rights from AD into the new application being written. Was wondering if any one has any idea how to do so.

The application is being written using python.

Comment: File permissions are not held in active directory, but in the NTFS file system access control lists.

Comment: Absolutely right! Forgot What I was saying. I mean User Permissions inside AD instead of File permissions.